# Can I always find a smooth bundle map relating two arbitrary smooth vector fields defined on the same smooth manifold?

Tags: differential-geometry, smooth-manifolds, vector-fields, tangent-bundle

Suppose to consider two arbitrary smooth vector fields $X: M\rightarrow TM$ and $Y: M\rightarrow TM$ defined on the same differentiable manifold $M$. Is there always a smooth map $A: TM\rightarrow TM$ (or a composition of smooth maps, none of them necessarily induced by a diffeomorphism $\varphi: M\rightarrow M$), such that $Y=A(X)$?

If the answer is no, what are the conditions under which I can find such a smooth map $A$?

If you know the answer, could you please suggest me a reference where this problem is treated?

Comment: There is a natural isotopy from every section of a vector bundle to the 0 section. Now apply the isotopy extension theorem.

Comment: In the case where $X$ is nonvanishing you can even do this with a vector bundle morphism - fix an arbitrary Riemannian metric and let $A(V) = |X|^{-2}\langle V,X \rangle Y$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The vector space structure makes this quite simple: we can do this using a fiberwise translation of the tangent bundle. More explicitly, define $A: TM \to TM$ by $$A(V_p) = V_p + Y_p - X_p.$$ In standard coordinates $(x^i, dx^i)$  on the tangent bundle this is simply $A^i(p,V) = (p, V^i + Y^i - X^i)$, so it smooth by the smoothness of $X,Y$; and the desired property $A(X) = Y$ is clear.

Comment: Thank you! Now I would like to generalize this map in the case when $p$ is not mapped into itself, but to another arbitrary point $q$ by means of a diffeomorphism $\varphi : M\rightarrow M$, i.e. $q=\varphi(p)$. I would say that I should accordingly pushforward the vector fields and then apply the map $A$ that you proposed. Am I right?

Comment: So what's the desired relation? $AX=Y\varphi$?

Comment: Yes, this is the desired relation. But is this $A$ defined in the same way as you proposed before? If not, what would be its expression in standard coordinates now?

Comment: The natural generalization seems to be $A(V_p) = V_{\varphi (p)} + Y_{\varphi (p)} - X_{\varphi (p)}.$ *If* you choose different coordinates on the domain and range that are $\varphi$-related (i.e. so that $\varphi$ is represented locally by the identity function of $\mathbb R^n$) then this will have the same coordinate expression as before.

Comment: I think your last comment answers my question. According to this generalization, we have $Y_{\varphi (p)}=A(X_p) \forall X,Y,\varphi$.

Comment: Then, if one wants to write explicitly the pushforward, one can redefine $A$ to be $$ A(V_p)=V_p+Y_p-X_p, $$as before, and then write $$ Z_{\varphi (p)}=\varphi_*\left( A(V_p) \right)=\varphi_*\left( V_p+Y_p-X_p\right), $$because the pushforward is linear. Therefore we have $$ Y_{\varphi (p)}=\varphi_*\left( A(X_p) \right)=\varphi_*\left( X_p+Y_p-X_p\right). $$ Is this all consistent with what you wrote?

Comment: Also, we now considered a specific form for $A$. In general, for arbitrary smooth $X$ and $Y$, are there any constraints on the form of $A$, other than $Y_{\varphi (p)}=A(X_p)$? In other words, provided that $Y_{\varphi (p)}=A(X_p)$ holds, how many $A$ can I find?

Comment: @Frank: if you're just requiring that $A$ be a smooth fibre bundle map then there will be an infinite-dimensional space of such $A$ - something roughly the size of the diffeomorphism group of a manifold. This is because $X$ picks out only a single point in each tangent space, so the value of $A$ is prescribed only on an $n$-dimensional subspace of the $2n$-dimensional tangent bundle. Thus we have a huge freedom to deform $A$ so long as we leave the image of $X$ alone.

Comment: If you require more structure you get a more manageable amount of freedom - for example if you require $A$ to be a fiberwise translation then it is uniquely determined, or if you require it to be fiberwise affine then the admissible $A$ will look like $GL(TM)$.

Comment: The requirement is that $A: TM \rightarrow TM$ is a smooth automorphism of the tangent bundle of a Hausdorff, paracompact, not compact, smooth 4-dimensional pseudo-Riemannian manifold, such that $Y_{\varphi (p)}=A(X_p)$.

Comment: Automorphisms of what kind of object? If vector bundle automorphisms then there might be none at all (if $X$ vanishes somewhere $Y$ doesn't). If smooth fibre bundle or affine bundle then "really big" or "$GL(TM)$ big" respectively, as described above.

Comment: Automorphism of the tangent bundle, which is a vector bundle. I am requiring it to be an automorphism because I want to preserve the structure of the tangent bundle. About the vanishing of $X$, that is why I wanted to change the point $p$ too. If $X$ vanishes at $p$ and $Y$ vanishes at $q$, I can find a diffeomorphism such that $q=\varphi (p)$ and the above should still hold. The problem is when the two vector fields vanish a different number of times. Would you say, in that case, that such an automorphism does not exist?

Comment: @Frank: The tangent bundle is a vector bundle, but also thus an affine bundle, smooth fibre bundle, topological fibre bundle, etc... always good to be clear. If $X$ vanishes more often than $Y$ then no such linear automorphism exists - remember that a linear map must send $0$ to $0$.

Comment: If $X$ and $Y$ vanish the same number of times, how many such $A$ (and $\varphi$) can I find? Still an infinite number?

Comment: @Frank: if there are any at all there will be infinitely many. You might need to be careful about the nature of the zeroes - if $Y$ has simple zeroes while $X$ has higher-order zeroes then I don't think there are any.